# Regex EOL replace with perl is giving unexpected results

Tags: regex, linux, perl

**Why is there a dollar sign at the starting of line 2 and line 3?**

```bash
➜ echo -e "hello\nworld" | perl -pe 's/$/\$/g'
hello$
$world$
$%
```

Above, I am trying to add a dollar sign at the end of each line, but somehow it's appending a dollar sign at the beginning too. It does that when global flag is enabled. But when I remove the global flag, it works fine:

```bash
➜ echo -e "hello\nworld" | perl -pe 's/$/\$/'
hello$
world$
```

Can anyone explain what's happening? Maybe it has something to do with '\r\n' characters?

**EDIT : Adding the lookbehind case**

It's not just breaking in this cases, but other cases as well. Consider the following:

```bash
➜ echo -e "A\nB\nC\nD" | perl -pe 's/(?<!A)$/\$/'
A
$B$
C$
D$
```

Above, I want to mark rows which don't end in "A" with $.
The extra dollar sign in line 2 shouldn't be there. I'm not even using global flag.

---

**SOLUTION** : Okay got it now. The solution for second one is like this (for explanation, refer to [Wiktor Stribiżew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045574/2208483))

```bash
➜ echo -e "A\nB\nC\nD" | perl -pe 's/(?<!A|\n)$/\$/'
A
B$
C$
D$
```

But **beware**, if you try with more than single characters, it will throw
`Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex`. For example:

```bash
➜ echo -e "AA\nBB\nCC\nDD" | perl -pe 's/(?<!AA|\n)$/\$/'
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!AA|\n)$/ at -e line 1.
```

To solve this, add the appropriate number of `.` before newline.

```bash
➜ echo -e "AA\nBB\nCC\nDD" | perl -pe 's/(?<!AA|.\n)$/\$/'
AA
BB$
CC$
DD$
```

Comment: because of  variable length lookbehind other workarounds to use multiple negative lookbehind `s/(?<!AA)(?<!\n)$/\$/`, or use negative lookahead `s/(?<!AA)(?!\z)$/\$/`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, why does that work? Are multiple lookbehinds naturally ORed?

Comment: each lookbehind adds a new constraint so is more restricive like `and` condition : when cursor position matches `$` the first lookbehind tells engine to check the two last char are not `AA`, the second checks that the last char is not `\n`, about the other workaround the second check is a lookahead to check it's not anchored to the very end of input

Comment: otherwise as `$` doesn't match exactly what is expected it can just be changed to `(?=\n)` : `echo -e "AA\nBB\nCC\nDD" | perl -pe 's/(?<!AA)(?=\n)/\$/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `$` is a zero-width assertion and it can match before a final newline. Perl reads a line with a trailing `\n`, so `$` matches twice: before and after that.

Your string basically goes to Perl as two lines:

```
hello\n
world\n
```

And the `$` can match both before a final newline and at the very end of the string. Thus, there are two matches in both lines ("strings" in this context).

If you want to match the very end of string, use `\z`:

```
perl -pe 's/\z/\$/g'
```

since `\z` only matches the *very* end of the string, but it is not likely anyone would want to use that since it will effectively insert a `$` at the *start*  of the second and subsequent lines, adding it as the final line as well.

To only insert `$` before the last `\n` and stop, use your `perl -pe 's/$/\$/'`, with no `g` modifier.

Comment: I have tried your command but it still gives me:

`echo -e "hello\nworld" | perl -pe 's/\z/\$/g'                                                                                                
hello\n
$world\n
$`

Comment: Yes, it is expected since it matches the end of string after `\n`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Okay now I'm on the right track. Thanks for removing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use it with the global replace, you can use the following command:

```
echo -e "hello\nworld" | perl -pe 's/^(.*)$/\1\$/g'                                                                                          
hello$
world$
```

or without back-references you can use:

```
echo -e "hello\nworld" | perl -pe 's/\n$/\$\n/g'
hello$
world$
```

you might need to replace `\n` by `\r\n` if you manipulate a file from windows or just use `dos2unix` to remove Windows EOL chars `\r`.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it, but my question is why that is happening? Because it's not just creating problem for this case, it's also creating problem in the other cases. I'll add other cases in my post. Also, your second solution will break if you do: echo -ne "hello\nworld"